# Nav Drawer Home Button does not open drawer after opening another activity and going back

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have a particular situation where, I have a parent `Activity` which extends `ActionBarActivity` in that `Activity` I declare and initialize my `DrawerLayout` with all the boiler plate code for implementing a **Navigation Drawer**

Then to save time I created new `Activities` which extend this `DrawerActivity` in my code so you can open the navigation drawer in all these activities.

The problem occurs when this happens:

Assume Activities are:

```
Activity A = [A]
Activity B = [B]
```

Both extend `DrawerActivity`

```
[A] --- Open Drawer and Open --> [B] --- Press Back Button ---> [A]
```

The Navigation Drawer opens from the `Home Button` when you are in `[A]`, but when I press the back button from `[B]` I can't open the Navigation Drawer from the `Home Button` but I can slide out the drawer.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong here, I was wondering if there was an issue with `ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()` but I tried implementing that everywhere I could and it didn't solve the problem.

Like I mentioned above all the boiler plate code is already written, example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(recyclerView)) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(recyclerView);
                mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            } else if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(recyclerView)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(recyclerView);
                mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.action_logout:
            new DeauthorizeTask().execute();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have overriden `onOptionsItemSelected()` correctly.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
      return true;
    }
    // Handle your other action bar items...

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Actually I might have forgotten the portion where you call the .onOptionItemSelected(item) on the DrawerToggle. Is there any way that you would suggest this for switch statements? Please see code above.

Comment: Don't worry about providing sample code, surrounding the switch statement with that if statement solved the issue. Thanks Apurva!

Comment: i am getting the same issue but this answer does not solve it